# not able to update gridview

Tags: c#

I am not able to update gridview in C# by using below code.

```
 protected void grdreg_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            con.Open();
            HiddenField id = ((HiddenField)(grdreg.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblid")));
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update NEW_TABLE SET FIRST_NAME=@FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME=@LAST_NAME WHERE ID=@ID", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FIRST_NAME",((TextBox)(grdreg.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtfname"))).Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LAST_NAME",((TextBox)(grdreg.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtlname"))).Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id.Value);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
            grdreg.EditIndex = -1;
            con.Close();
            fillgridview();

        }
```

when i update the textbox value and debug the code it will show the the previous value not the updated value of textbox.

please do needful.

Comment: I think here you are updating the values and selecting again from database. For this you can simply write the following code and bind data with a select query. Please check the select query,update string etc. Also it will be better if you disclose the ' fillgridview();'

Comment: R u able to got the value in hidden field and your ID column is integer? if yes then first convert hidden field value to integer and try....

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using the [RowUpdating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating.aspx) event. Use [RowUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdated.aspx) Event to get the updated value  from the control. During RowUpdating event the controls value is not yet updated.